# Mapping C code to existing Unit Test code

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pre-written Test Code written In C.

I am trying to write code that should compile based on that test code. Basically it is about pointers.
I have tried scripting something but it keeps on returning "Failed".

Below is the snippet to the test Pre-written Code:

```
#define TEST_LBS    5.5
int testConvertLbsG(void)
{
double lbs = TEST_LBS;
int intA, intB, fail = 0;

printf("---------------------------\n");
printf("Function: convertLbsG\n");
printf("---------------------------\n");

// Test-1: argument and return value
intA = intB = 0;
printf("Test-1: ");
intB = convertLbsG(&lbs, &intA);
if (intA == intB && intA == TEST_LBSG)
{
    printf("<PASSED>\n");
}
else
{
    printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
    fail++;
}
// Test-2: return value only
intA = intB = 0;
printf("Test-2: ");
intA = convertLbsG(&lbs, NULL);
if (intA == TEST_LBSG)
{
    printf("<PASSED>\n");
}
else
{
    printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
    fail++;
}

// Test-3: argument only
intA = intB = 0;
printf("Test-3: ");
convertLbsG(&lbs, &intA);
if (intA == TEST_LBSG)
{
    printf("<PASSED>\n");
}
else
{
    printf("<!!! FAILED !!!>\n");
    fail++;
}
```

Below is the code I have been trying to write to match up and compile based on the test code above:

```
int convertLbsKg(double *x ,double *y) {
while (true) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        if (x != NULL) {
            double value;
            x = &value;

            y = x;
            *y = value;

            }
        return;
    }

}   
}
```

I would appreciate some help on where I am going wrong

Comment: The condition `x >= 0` makes no sense since `x` is a pointer. You also seem to misunderstand how emulating pass by reference works in C (if that's what you're doing), since `x = &value` is wrong on multiple levels (the assignment itself will be lost once the function returns, and the pointer itself will immediately become invalid once the function returns and the variable `value` ceases to exist).

Comment: And the assignments `x = &value`, `y = x` and `*y = value` doesn't make sense either. It's essentially the same as `value = value`. And `value` isn't even initialized, so it will  have an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 1):

Using the correct return type, descriptive variable names, const the value you don't change, correct logic (the original code makes no sense to me), and I added the asserts that I would add to catch null pointers:

```
int convertLbsKg(const double *weight_in_lbs, int *weight_in_kg) {
   assert(weight_in_lbs);
   if(!weight_in_kg) return 0;
   return *weight_in_kg = 0.4535924 * (*weight_in_lbs);
}
```

Comment: Note that [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) is a conditional macro. If the macro `NDEBUG` is defined (common for release builds) then `assert` is a no-op. And when "enabled" it would cause the program to crash rather than fail gracefully.

Comment: You are right of course.  This is homework and there will never be a release build.  Personally, I don't set NDEBUG for release builds either, as I want to catch those type of (logic?) errors as soon as possible.  If the function is expected to handle null as part of it's specification then you use a condition instead.  There is no way for this function signature to signal error (errno-style excluded as bad practice; I guess you could technically use a jmp but I never have).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the snippet. however, I keep running into the following error  ```read access violation. y was nullptr```

Comment: @Nickson Don't thank me, it wasn't me who wrote the answer. :)

Comment: That was for @AllanWind. Didn't see it clearly :-)

Comment: @Nickson I didn't use the variable y in the current snippet of code above, nor does your test program pass in  a null pointer.  I therefor argue that the error is unrelated to this question.  Prove me wrong :-)

Comment: @AllanWind I have edited your code because I need to write the code without declaring any value as you have done with ```0.4535924```. I just changed the variables ```weight_in_lbs``` and ```weight_in_kg``` to ```x``` and ```y``` respectively

Comment: @AllanWind ```Assertion failed for value y```

Comment: @Nickson 0.4535924 is a constant (or factor) of an expression and not a declaration.  That requirement makes no sense.  It still doesn't explain how a null pointer is being passed in.  If x is null what should the return value and y be?  If y is null what should the return value be?  Your test doesn't specify.

Comment: @AllanWind I have posted the complete code, the error is returned on 'Test-2'

Comment: @Nickson in other words, I answered your original question, and you changed it.  I updated my answer to pass your 2nd test.  Please open a new question if you need help, ideally, after you think about how to fix yourself first.  accept answer and upvote if helpful.

Comment: And file a bug against your test suite.  It confounds errors and valid values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229807/discussion-between-nickson-and-allan-wind).